# How can I add a custom boolean query into influxDb

Tags: select, grafana, influxdb

wondering if someone can help me with this.

I want to have a select query that returns a boolean based on two different fields.  For example

```
   SELECT (sum("value_1")=count("value_2")) as test FROM "measurement"
```

would like this to return true or false, but can't seem to get it to work.  I would like to use this as a singlestat in grafana.  Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Not exactly what you want but close - using subqueries: `SELECT count(s) as test FROM (SELECT sum("value_1") as s, count("value_2") as c FROM "measurement") WHERE s=c`

Comment: that could work thanks